# Run ssh commande by java to launch script in ec2 instance

Tags: java, bash, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a script in amazon machine and i would run this script using ssh from netbeans.
i use this code :

```
String myKey="/home/local/my_key.pem";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String commande = "ssh -i "+myKey+" ubuntu@ec2-53-71-22-288.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 'bash runFile.bash' -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ";

Process p = runtime.exec(commande);
p.waitFor();
```

But it does not work. When i print `p.getErrorStream()` I obtain:

```
bash: writeFile.bash: command not found
```

When i run the `commande` from `bash` it works but in netbeans no !

Someone can explain me why ? other solution please ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you get? an error message? can you add it to the question?

Comment: No error, just the command line does not make what it should do !

Comment: yes nothing. It seems it works correctly, but it does not.

Comment: Are you waiting for the process to return? (`p.waitFor()`)

Comment: I tried and it's the same. ( i edited my post)

Comment: what is returned? you can also read `p`'s `getOutputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` to see if you can see what the problems may be

Comment: @UriAgassi This getErrorStream() gives :

Warning: Identity file ~/local/my_key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: and... is there a `~/local/my_key.pem`?

Comment: Indeed, the path was incorrect. Now i specify the correct path but i obtain a new error : bash: writeFile.bash: command not found

Comment: What is `writeFile.bash`? is it a file you are trying to execute? is it where it is supposed to be? is it executable? try executing `./writeFile.bash`

Comment: It works with ./writeFile.bash. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Make it unswer if you want to close the discussion and validate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String myKey="/home/local/my_key.pem";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String commande = "ssh -i "+myKey+" ubuntu@ec2-53-71-22-288.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 'bash ./runFile.bash' -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ";

Process p = runtime.exec(commande);
p.waitFor();
```

(use `bash ./runFile.bash` instead of `bash runFile.bash`)